# Why we didn't use * during dereferencing the pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers, string.h, strdup

In the below code, we get a pointer from strdup(source) and we store it in a pointer named target.
Now, when we print the string using pointer, we don't add * at the beginning of the pointer: why is it so? As I studied whenever we want to dereference any pointer we use *pointer_name. If we add * in the below code, we get an error.
I am very beginner, so pls ans in easy words.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
 
int main()
{
    char source[] = "Programming";
 
    char* target = strdup(source);
 
    printf("%s\n",target);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to dereference a pointer in your code? If you dereference it, you only get a single `char`. `printf` would not know where the other characters of that string are. Therefore you don't dereference it but let `printf` dereference it. And if you don't dereference, you don't add a `*` anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

`printf` expects a char pointer in the place of the `%s` specifier.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 1):

```
char* target = strdup(source);
printf("%s\n",target);
```

> Why we don't use *target in the code above?

The explanation is quite simple, as already stated in previous answers: *target* has type char pointer, which is exactly what printf() wants in the above call.

Now, printf() is a little complicated because its semantic is not simple - basically it accepts zero or more arguments after the first, of any type (possibly applying *promotion*). But if we use strdup() again, maybe it is simpler:

```
char* target2 = strdup(target);
```

Here, if you wrote strdup(*target), the compiler might warn that you are passing a char instead of a pointer to char.

Answer (score 0):

`strdup()` returns a `char*`, hence the `char*` type of `target`. `target` holds a pointer to the *first character* in an array of `char`s. `printf("%s", string)` expects `string` to be a `char*`, so there’s no reason to do anything to `target`; just pass it to `printf()`.

If you dereferenced `target`, you would get a single `char` (`P` in this case). `printf()` would then complain that you had supplied a character instead of a string (pointer to character). Even worse, the program could compile, and then `printf()` would try to print the string at address `P` (`0x50`), which would result in probably unwanted behaviour.

When working with arrays—a string is a type of array—you rarely want to dereference the array.

Comment: It's possible (maybe even probable) that `printf` wouldn't notice that you passed a `char` instead of a pointer, and the result would be much worse.

Comment: GCC gives me a warning, but not an error. I’ll update my answer to reflect that. `warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'`

Comment: I think the compiler emits "has type int" because by dereferencing a char* you obtain a char which can't be pushed on the stack, so it is promoted to int.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica there's no problem with a char as a parameter type, but `printf` is special - as a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) any char parameter is *always* promoted to int.